# Can't access collection from the shell - SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1

Tags: mongodb

I wrote a script that uses mongoimport to load csv files into mongodb. When I run this for two similar csv files (of the same type) both upload fine, however I can only access one of them from the mongodb shell. Here is a transcript of a mongodb shell session:

```
> show collections
3mLgQAYJCq6_20110802
eTByWMY7zO6_20110802NonUniCode
system.indexes
> db.3mLgQAYJCq6_20110802
Thu Aug 18 18:44:49 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1
> db.eTByWMY7zO6_20110802NonUniCode
vh.eTByWMY7zO6_20110802NonUniCode
```

However, I can access both collections from a python script and using mongoexport. I suspect there is a problem with the 3mLgQAYJCq6_20110802 file but I don't know where to start looking. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

This works for me when my collection names include special characters:

```
db["3mLgQAYJCq6_20110802"].findOne();
```

Comment: findOne() returns for me null, but other methods works great. find(), drop(), remove() etc. Clue is db["3mLgQAYJCq6_20110802"]

Comment: +1 This worked for me. I had underscores and a hyphen in my collection name.

Answer (score 3):

The collection name should start with a letter or the underscore.You can get the info about the naming convention for the collections in mongodb from below link-
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Collections

Answer (score -1):

lovely collection names... it's probably because it's starts with a `3`.