# MongoDB SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell)

Tags: mongodb

When I try to invoke methods of a collection, why is there an error of `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell)`? Thanks.

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.8
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-08-04T11:58:21.138-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-04T11:58:21.138-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-08-04T11:58:21.138-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-08-04T11:58:21.138-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-04T11:58:21.139-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-08-04T11:58:21.139-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-08-04T11:58:21.139-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 

> show dbs
mydb   0.000GB
local  0.000GB
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
> show collections
201607012
> db
mydb
> mydb.201607012.find()
2016-08-04T12:10:23.826-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:4

> db.201607012.find()
2016-08-04T12:10:29.000-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:2

> db.201607012.find()
2016-08-04T12:11:09.115-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:2

> db.201607012.stats()
2016-08-04T12:13:06.022-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:2
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions)

> Collection names should begin with an underscore or a letter character

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790049/numeric-collection-name-remove) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111830/cant-access-collection-from-the-shell-syntaxerror-missing-before-statement) how to remove or access your wrongly named collection.

Answer (score 35):

exit from mongoshell with quit() and try to run command in regular command prompt, it will work

Answer (score 8):

You have to open new cmd and run as administrator then write mongoexport.
It worked in my mongoDB

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on this? It's not working for me.