# How to call MongoDB commands using .bat file

Tags: windows, mongodb, batch-file

I'm trying to execute MongoDB command *(for create DB)* using .bat file.

For that I've tried:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
mongo 
mongo --eval "use MyDatabase"
pause
```

But it gives an error `missing ; before statement @(shell eval):1:4` 
How can I solve this issue?

Side: I've already gone through [MongoDB SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772594/mongodb-syntaxerror-missing-before-statement-shell)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you try with :

```
cd Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
mongo.exe 
mongo.exe --eval "use MyDatabase"
pause
```

I am using a .bat file which works properly and contains this

```
cd \Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
mongod.exe
pause
```

**EDIT**

I tested a file like this and it works fine (create db, collection and document)

**mongodb.bat**

```
cd \Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
mongo.exe db-mydb --eval "db.yourCollection.insert({key:'value'});"
pause
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want to run your .bat file on the background, i have made a .VBS file which works properly

**mongodb.VBS**

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Path\To\Your\mongodb.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It's not showing any error, but it doesn't create a DB

Comment: If you want to create a new database, I think you have to insert a new document inside

Comment: You mean collection? I've tried with add `mongo.exe --eval "db.createCollection('testcollecation')"` but no luck :(

Comment: Can you try with something like this ? mongo.exe --eval "db.yourCollection.insert({"key":"value"})"

Answer (score 3):

- Put this code in your bat file.
- It'll start and activate the mongodb in 2 different admin privileged cmd windows.
- Please check the paths before to adjust to your environment.

> START "runas /user:administrator" cmd /K "cd C:\Program
> Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin &  mongod.exe --dbpath c:\data\db"
>
> TIMEOUT /T 10 START
>
> START "runas /user:administrator" cmd /K "cd C:\Program
> Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin &  mongo.exe "

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
mongo.exe 
mongo.exe --eval "use MyDatabase"
pause
```

or use a text file script.txt containing your commands and write batch file as:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
mongo.exe mydb < script.txt
```

can use full path if file is at different location.