# I try to create a Database in MongoDb. But I have syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I try to create a Database in MongoDB. It should have seven collections and that one collection has another collection. I created this in terminal

```
db.Nothern province.insert({_id:1}{Distric:{Jaffna:{Zones:{Jaffna:},
{Valikamam:},{Thenmaradchy:},{Vadamarachchy:},{Islands:}}},{Kilinochchi:
{Zones:{Kilinochchi:}}},{Mullaitivu:{Zones:{Mullaitivu:}}},{Vavuniya:{Zones:
{Thunukkai:},{Vavuniya North:},{Vavuniya South:}}},{Mannar:{Zones:{Mannar:},
{Madhu:}}}})
```

but I received this error

```
[thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:11
```

Is this code correct or wrong?

How can I solve this?

Comment: The space in 'Nothern province' throws the error.
1:11 means: first line position 11. I don't know how to handle spaces in MongoDB collections. Sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772594/mongodb-syntaxerror-missing-before-statement-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`getCollection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.getCollection/) function.

Example:

```
db.getCollection("Nothern province").insert({
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In mongoDB When the first collection is created then the Database is automatically created because of it is **Document Oriented** and **Schema Less**

> **For Example:** `

```
use testDatabase
```

It will not create Database But your db object is pointing to the 
testDatabse if you run the below command then it will create a Database along with a collection named as : **myColl**

```
db.runCommand ( {
   create: "myColl",
   collation: { locale: "fr" }
});`
```

now run a command **show dbs** command on the mongo shell. you are able to see the **testDatabase** named database  and after that run command **show collections** or **show tables** you are able to see the **myColl** named collection

Comment: But I have one doubt, I would like to save the datas in student marks. that student marks is should be this way.
Province->Distric->Zone->School name->Grade10->Subject->Student marks

Comment: At any level of mongodb you are able to access the array as well as JSON object and you can push also the json object to any of the level for example                                                                                                       Province->Distric->Zone->School name->Grade10->Subject->Student-marks  @sutudent marks you have push json like this {"student_marks":{ marks: 243, date: new Date()}}