# Cannot backup mongo database due to command execution error

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, shell

Here is the official command for backing up the database from **cloud.mongodb.com**

[image]

When I run it in shell with the appropriate password and correct db name I get the following error:

[js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:12

The database name is **school**

I've searched for the error and only found the following: [MongoDB SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772594/mongodb-syntaxerror-missing-before-statement-shell). It says that the db name should begin with an **underscore** or a **letter** which it does in my case.

What am I missing?

Comment: You looked at the wrong answer. You are attempting to run in the "mongo shell" when you are **supposed** to run in the **OS shell**. There's even an [FAQ on the manual page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#synopsis) because so many people do this. - *"Run mongoexport from the system command line, not the mongo shell.*"

Comment: OMG, how could I have done that... Tnx immensely for pointing it out.